# Render named children in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal component which take a trigger to open the modal, and the content to go inside the modal.

```
<Modal>
  <button className="btn btn--primary">Open modal</button>
  <div>
    <p>Modal content</p>
    <p>More modal content</p>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

And in the Modal component:

```
  return (
    <div className="Modal">
      {props.children[0]}
      <div className="Modal__container">
        <div className="Modal__header">
          <button className="Modal__close btn btn--secondary btn--small">
            Close
          </button>
          <h1 className="Modal__heading">Here is my modal</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="Modal__content">{props.children[1]}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

This is working but very fragile as Im using an index on props.children. Can I instead name the components I pass to Modal? So something like:

```
<Modal>
  <Modal.Trigger>
    <button className="btn btn--primary">Open modal</button>
  </Modal.Trigger>
  <Modal.Content>
    <p>Modal content</p>
    <p>More modal content</p>
  </Modal.Content>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use props instead:

declare your Modal like so:

```
<Modal action={<button className="btn btn--primary">Open modal</button>}>
  <div>
    <p>Modal content</p>
    <p>More modal content</p>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

and your render method will then look something like

```
return (
  <div className="Modal">
    {props.action}
    <div className="Modal__container">
      <div className="Modal__header">
        <button className="Modal__close btn btn--secondary btn--small">
          Close
        </button>
        <h1 className="Modal__heading">Here is my modal</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="Modal__content">{props.children[1]}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your children with a boolean flag that will serve as a name.

Within `Modal` you find the child marked as `trigger` and the child marked as `content`:

```
// within Modal
render() {
  let trigger, content;
  React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
    if (!child) return;
    if (child.props.trigger) { trigger = child }
    if (child.props.content) { content = child }
  })

  return (
    <div className="Modal">
      {trigger}
      <div className="Modal__container">
        <div className="Modal__header">
          <button className="Modal__close btn btn--secondary btn--small">
            Close
          </button>
        <h1 className="Modal__heading">Here is my modal</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="Modal__content">
        {content}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And you mark the appropriate children when rendering `Modal`:

```
<Modal>
  <button trigger className="btn btn--primary">Open modal</button>
  <div content>
    <p>Modal content</p>
    <p>More modal content</p>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

We wrote a library called [`seapig`](https://github.com/enkidevs/seapig) that you might find useful for this use case.

Comment: When I console.log(React.Children) I can see I have access to a forEach whose length is 3, however when I use your code as is my components are undefined.

Comment: This doenst not log anything:     React.Children.forEach(child => {
      console.log('something');
    });

Comment: @Evans I forgot to pass in the children, fixed now

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Comment: Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the ReactMeteorDataComponent component.

Comment: (Im using Meteor but I dont think this should affect this issue)

Comment: @Evans make sure you are marking your children as `trigger` and `content`

Comment: I am. When I console.log(Trigger) it works but when I add <Trigger /> to the return function is errors. Im currently not rendering <Content /> while I debug.

Comment: What does `console.log(Trigger)` log?

Comment: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "button", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}

Comment: That looks correct. What's the error when you do `<Trigger />`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160758/discussion-between-evans-and-nem035).